# Is it possible to change from VIP to SNI on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I'm getting ready to roll out a PHP application hosted on Google App Engine. It needs to have SSL support and I'm trying to decide between SNI and VIP. There may be a chance some Windows XP users access the site, but probably not. My thought was to start out using VIP, check the Analytics to see if there are any Windows XP users, then switch to SNI if possible.

Can a switch like this be made? If so, do you have any thoughts on the process of doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Yes (never used VIP, tho).

[The Purchasing VIP doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl?hl=en#how_to_purchase) shows the available SSL certificate serving modes are "SNI only" and "SNI + VIP 411", so SNI is always there.

So it appears as all you'd need to do to revert is to, in the <del>Google Apps Admin console</del> Google Developer Console -> [your app] -> Compute -> App Engine -> Settings select the `SSL Certificates` tab, select the respective SSL certificate and change its serving mode back to SNI-only. Then remove the VIP (back in the Google Apps Admin console). Maybe also drop/update the DNS CNAME for the ex-VIP?